# Wrap groups of nodes without attribute in XSLT

Tags: xslt, grouping, nodes

I want to wrap groups of elements with a new parent element. Such groups appear in many places in the document. The elements have no attribute.
With `for-each-group` I manage to include all desired elements of the document in a large group with a new parent element, but I want to distinguish the groups according to their occurrence. Found many similar questions and answers, but could not solve the problem.

**My document**

```
<modul>
    <body>
        <Standard>some text</Standard>
        <Herausforderung>some text</Herausforderung>
        <Standard>some text
           <d2tb>some text</d2tb>
        </Standard>
        <Aufzhlungbullets>some text</Aufzhlungbullets>
        <Aufzhlungbullets>some text</Aufzhlungbullets>
        <Aufzhlungbullets>some text</Aufzhlungbullets>
        <Standard>some text
           <d2ti>some text</d2ti>
        </Standard0>
        <Aufzhlungbullets>some text</Aufzhlungbullets>
        <Aufzhlungbullets>some text</Aufzhlungbullets>
        <Aufzhlungbullets>some text</Aufzhlungbullets>
        <Standard>some text</Standard>
   </body>
</modul>
```

**Desired output**

```
<modul>
        <body>
            <Standard>some text</Standard>
            <Herausforderung>some text</Herausforderung>
            <Standard>some text
               <d2tb>some text</d2tb>
            </Standard>
            <list>
               <Aufzhlungbullets>some text</Aufzhlungbullets>
               <Aufzhlungbullets>some text</Aufzhlungbullets>
               <Aufzhlungbullets>some text</Aufzhlungbullets>
            </list>
            <Standard>some text
               <d2ti>some text</d2ti>
            </Standard0>
            <list>
               <Aufzhlungbullets>some text</Aufzhlungbullets>
               <Aufzhlungbullets>some text</Aufzhlungbullets>
               <Aufzhlungbullets>some text</Aufzhlungbullets>
            </list>
            <Standard>some text</Standard>
       </body>
    </modul>
```

**My XSLT-stylesheet**

```
<xsl:template match="body">
        <list>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Aufzhlungbullets" group-by=".">
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        </list>
    </xsl:template>
```

note: I know that this template suppresses all other content. At first I concentrated on getting the grouping right. The contents of the rest of the document should of course be visible, but I don't think that's a major problem.

With this template I only get all  elements in a large group.

```
<modul>
    <list>
      <Aufzhlungbullets>some text</Aufzhlungbullets>
      <Aufzhlungbullets>some text</Aufzhlungbullets>
      <Aufzhlungbullets>some text</Aufzhlungbullets>
      <Aufzhlungbullets>some text</Aufzhlungbullets>
      <Aufzhlungbullets>some text</Aufzhlungbullets>
      <Aufzhlungbullets>some text</Aufzhlungbullets>
      <Aufzhlungbullets>some text</Aufzhlungbullets>
   </list>
</modul>
```

I tried a lot of variations of my template - without success. How can I differentiate that the wanted elements appear in different groups in the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `group-adjacent` on the `xsl:for-each-group` instead, grouping adjacent nodes by their name, and wrapping the group in a `<list>` tag if it it a `Aufzhlungbullets` node:

```
<xsl:template match="body">
    <list>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="local-name()">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="self::Aufzhlungbullets">
                    <list>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()" />    
                    </list>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </list>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Very good, thx. It works. I didn´t use local-name() for group-adjacent in my attempts.